# Re-looping through an array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a strange array. I get some objects that have children, and then I have some objects that are the id's of the children.

```
array {
"1": {
    "children": [
    10,
    11,

    ],
     "parent_id": null,
  }         
}   

"2": {
    "children": [
        12,
        13,
    ]
    "parent_id": null,
}

"10": {
      "name": Tom,
      "parentid": 1,
     }

"11": { 
          "name": Peter,
           "parentid": 1,
     }

}
```

I'm trying to first list out the objects if they have children via a foreach.

```
foreach ($array as $key) {
    if (parent_id === null){
       echo id;
    }
}
```

So I get a list that looks like this:

```
 1
 2
```

(no 10 and 11)

But now what I want to do is list the name of the children under their parent, so it ends up something like this:

```
1
  Tom
  Peter
2
```

I have an array of the children ids, I'm just not sure how to reloop through the original array for the names.

Comment: Will the array always only have one level of inheritance? I.e. parent/child? Or will it ever have grandparent/parent/child or great-grandparent/grandparent/parent/child, etc?

Comment: Yes, just one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will assume your array is one level deep, a `parent_id == null` signifies a parent and there are no possible orphan elements that should be displayed:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if ($value['parent_id'] === null) {
       echo $key;
       // we got a parent, iterate through it's children
       foreach($value['children'] as $childId) {
           echo $array[$childId]['name'];
       }
   }
}
```

May want to add some [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks, just to make sure all keys exist in the array.